# How to perform band-structure unfolding in VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure

I have created a band structure for 3x3x1 doped-supercell using `VASP`, and I obtained the figure below. Now I want to do band-unfolding. What are the simplest ways to do that ?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the $3 \times 3 \times 1$ supercell and the $\Gamma-M-K-\Gamma$ path, I assume that you are investigating the band structure of a two-dimensional material with a hexagonal structure. Therefore, maybe the simplest way that you can follow immediately is using the [VASPKIT](https://vaspkit.com/index.html) package.

Coincidently, the example tutorial is about monolayer MoS2: https://vaspkit.com/tutorials.html#band-unfolding

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

#### BandUP: Band Unfolding code for Plane-wave based calculations

This software can help you. From the developers site:

> BandUP is a code that allows you to obtain a primitive cell representation of the band structure of systems simulated using supercells. The unfolding of the bands is performed as described in the following papers:
>
> Paulo V. C. Medeiros, Sven Stafström and Jonas Björk, [Phys. Rev. B 89,
> 041407(R) (2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.89.041407)
>
> Paulo V. C. Medeiros, Stepan S. Tsirkin, Sven Stafström and Jonas
> Björk, [Phys. Rev. B 91, 041116(R) (2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.91.041116)

Information about the code: http://www.ifm.liu.se/theomod/compphys/band-unfolding/

And source code ready to download: https://github.com/band-unfolding/bandup